# How to set first-child in multi class

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I have a question about css.
I want to change the color the first element of class 'active' which is "3".

This is my code, but it doesn't work.

```css
.item.active:first-child {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item clone" style="width:250px">1</div>
<div class="item clone" style="width:250px">2</div>
<div class="item active" style="width:250px">3</div>
<div class="item active" style="width:250px">4</div>
<div class="item active" style="width:250px">5</div>
<div class="item" style="width:250px">6</div>
<div class="item" style="width:250px">6</div>
```

And Is there any way to solve this problem with  Jquery???

Please help.

Comment: `:first-child` always refers to the first child of the **parent**. In this case, it refers to `1`. Adding classes to attempt to change the target does not change this behaviour.

Comment: nth-selectors reference the parent and siblings it ignores class

Comment: Its about jquery not with css so not duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `first` with `class` like this in jquery.

```js
$( ".active:first" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item clone" style="width:250px">1</div>
<div class="item clone" style="width:250px">2</div>
<div class="item active" style="width:250px">3</div>
<div class="item active" style="width:250px">4</div>
<div class="item active" style="width:250px">5</div>
<div class="item" style="width:250px">6</div>
<div class="item" style="width:250px">6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using owl carousel center event You can also achieved the same:   

 .center {
            color: red;
        }

     $('.nonloop').owlCarousel({
                    center: true,
                    items: 2,
                    loop: false,
                    margin: 10,
                    responsive: {
                        600: {
                            items: 4
                        }
                    }
                });
```